# Местоположение курсора в тексте

Tags: java, swing

В объекте класса JTextArea написан текст. Нужно создать функцию, которая будет добавлять определённый текст в то место, где расположен текстовый курсор.
Но как узнать местоположение курсора в тексте?

Comment: [`getCaretPosition()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getCaretPosition())?

Answer (score 1):

[Тут глядите](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html). Определяете место курсора, сравниваете находится ли он на вашем TextBox-е, если да, то выводите текст, если нет, то ничего не делаете.